# Check if string has numbers, letters and spaces

Tags: python, assert

I'm trying to come up with an assert statement that checks whether a nonempty string, s, contains alphanumeric characters and spaces:

```
    assert s.isalnum()
```

I understand that this will return False if there are spaces because it checks that whether every character is either a letter or number.  How do I fix this?

EDIT: For clarification, I'm trying to create an assert statement that checks whether a nonempty string contains alphanumeric characters and/or spaces.  For example, "    a 4    bc  " and "ab" should both return True.

Comment: Please provide some examples to help us understand your problem

Comment: Side note: `assert` is almost certainly wrong for this, you should `raise` an exception to valid inputs, `assert` is for sanity checks that conceptually can't fail

Comment: `if s.replace(' ','').isalnum() and ' ' in s: print('valid input')`

Comment: What is exactly your requirement? In your title you say _numbers, letters OR spaces_, but in the question you say _AND spaces_. So is your string supposed to contain all these (numbers, letters and spaces) or just one of them?

Comment: Sorry, my question is for numbers, letters, AND spaces.  My string may contain any of them (numbers, letters and spaces).  This is for a class and I'm supposed to use an assert statement to check for this.

Comment: _any of them_ sounds more like an OR, so you want to check if your string contains numbers, letters or spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
assert any(substr.issapce() or substr.isdigit() or substr.isalpha() for substr in s)
```

Strings for testing:

```
>>> s1 = '123 45    abc  67  d'
>>> s2 = '123456'
>>> s3 = 'abcd'
>>> s4 = ':?--==++'
```

Check whether a string contains any space:

```
>>> def hasAnySpace(str):
...   return ' ' in str
...
>>> hasAnySpace(s1)
True
>>> hasAnySpace(s2)
False
>>> hasAnySpace(s3)
False
>>> hasAnySpace(s4)
False
```

Check whether a string contains any digit, you can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function and [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function:

```
>>> def hasAnyDigit(str):
...   return any (substr.isdigit() for substr in str)
...
>>> hasAnyDigit(s1)
True
>>> hasAnyDigit(s2)
True
>>> hasAnyDigit(s3)
False
>>> hasAnyDigit(s4)
False
```

Check whether a string contains any alphabetic character, you can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function and [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) function:

```
>>> def hasAnyAlpha(str):
...   return any(substr.isalpha() for substr in str)
...
>>> hasAnyAlpha(s1)
True
>>> hasAnyAlpha(s2)
False
>>> hasAnyAlpha(s3)
True
>>> hasAnyAlpha(s4)
False
```

**Check whether a string contains any number, or any alphabetic character or any space**:

```
>>> def hasAnyAlNumSpace(str):
...   return any(substr.isalpha() or substr.isdigit() or substr.isspace() for substr in str)
...
>>> hasAnyAlNumSpace(s1)
True
>>> hasAnyAlNumSpace(s2)
True
>>> hasAnyAlNumSpace(s3)
True
>>> hasAnyAlNumSpace(s4)
False
```

If you want to use assert statement, you can use any combination of them:

```
>>> assert hasAnySpace(s1) or hasAnyDigit(s1) or hasAnyAlpha(s1) 
>>> assert hasAnySpace(s2) or hasAnyDigit(s2) or hasAnyAlpha(s2)
>>> assert hasAnySpace(s3) or hasAnyDigit(s3) or hasAnyAlpha(s3)
>>> assert hasAnySpace(s4) or hasAnyDigit(s4) or hasAnyAlpha(s4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
>>> assert hasAnySpace(s1)
>>> assert hasAnySpace(s2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
>>> assert hasAnyAlNumSpace(s1)
>>> assert hasAnyAlNumSpace(s2)
>>> assert hasAnyAlNumSpace(s3)
>>> assert hasAnyAlNumSpace(s4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Of course, if you don't like these methods, you can simply use assert like this:

```
assert ' ' in s1    
assert any(substr.isdigit() for substr in s1)
assert any(substr.isalpha() for substr in s1)
assert (' ' in s1) or any(substr.isdigit() or substr.isalpha() for substr in s1)
assert any(substr.issapce() or substr.isdigit() or substr.isalpha() for substr in s1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), to check if every character is alphanumeric or space:

```
text = "apple and 123"

result = all(c.isalnum() or c.isspace() for c in text)
print(result)

text = "with ."

result = all(c.isalnum() or c.isspace() for c in text)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

If it most contain spaces *and* alphanumeric characters, you can do:

```
def only_alnum_and_spaces(t):
    counts = {"spaces" : 0, "alnums": 0}
    for c in t:
        if c.isalnum():
            counts["alnums"] += 1
        elif c.isspace():
            counts["spaces"] += 1
        else:
            return False
    return counts["alnums"] > 0 and counts["spaces"] > 0

print(only_alnum_and_spaces("apple and 123"))
print(only_alnum_and_spaces("with ."))
print(only_alnum_and_spaces("appleand123"))
```

**Output**

```
True
False
False
```

Also note, as mentioned by @Chris_Rands that this .isspace considers tabs as whitespaces.

Comment: note `is.space()` also returns true for tabs and other whitespace

Comment: @usr2564301 Updated the answer. Also the title of the question says if must check if the string contains number, letters **or** spaces.

Comment: @usr2564301 requirement is not clear, in the title the OP says "OR spaces".

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the spaces to test:

```
assert s.replace(" ","").isalnum()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way

```
def customIsAlnum(String[] words):
    if(len(words) > 1):
       for(word in words):
           if(!word.isalnum()):
               return false
    else:
        return false
    return true


String str = "chelsea scored 3 goals"
String[] words = str.split()
print customIsAlnum(words)
```